# Read stream of an external process with Java

Tags: java, process, stream

What I would like to know is, can I from Java read the output stream of an external process? 
Let us say this external process is a windows terminal and is not started from Java using ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec().

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the external process is a predecessor in a process pipeline:

```
> cat file | java MyClass
```

then java program can read the output stream of the `cat` program via `System.in`. In other cases, I doubt it is possible even using C/C++ languages.

Comment: But if the external process was not started by Java, is it still possible?

Comment: When java starts another process, it uses system calls, and so does any other program, so there is no difference what program started the process.